# Using Protractor's 'browser' object with PhantomJS

Tags: phantomjs, protractor

I am trying to run a test suite written in Protractor headlessly (using PhantomJS), but when I run the command 'phantomjs testSuiteFile.js' I get the error: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: browser`. The browser variable is important in all of my tests so is there a way to allow phantomjs to find & use the browser object?

I also tried configuring my protractor config file to use phantomjs, I started selenium webdriver for phantomjs using the command recommended in the docs: `phantomjs --webdriver=9134` and ran the config file with `protractor protractor.conf.js`. The config file is set to only run myTest.js, and I now get the error `E/launcher - Error: Error: Cannot find module 'webpage'`. But myTest.js works when I run `phantomjs myTest.js`

myTest.js:

```
var WebPage = require('webpage');
page = WebPage.create();
page.open('http://google.com');
page.onLoadFinished = function() {
   page.render('googleScreenShot' + '.png');
   phantom.exit();}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not how `Protractor` and `PhantomJS` work together. You need to [execute `protractor` command from the command-line](http://www.protractortest.org/#/tutorial) to have `browser` and other Protractor global variables initialized.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I updated my question to include it